# Sequelize: findAll is not a function

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I just learning node.js by book.

I follow to instructions in the book and got an error. 
I spended couple of hours to find a problem, but without success.
Hope for your help and understanding.

```
exports.connectDB = function(){
var SQNote;
var sequlz;

if(SQNote) return SQNote.sync();

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(process.env.SEQUELIZE_CONNECT, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            reject(err);
        }
        else{
            resolve(data);
        }
    });
})
.then(yamltext => {
    return jsyaml.safeLoad(yamltext, 'utf-8');
})
.then(params => {
    sequlz = new Sequelize(params.dbname, 
        params.username, 
        params.password, 
        params.params);

    SQNote = sequlz.define('Note', {
                            notekey: {
                                    type: Sequelize.STRING,
                                    primaryKey: true,
                                    unique: true
                                },
                            title: Sequelize.STRING,
                            body: Sequelize.STRING
                        });
    return SQNote.sync;
});};
```

Error occurs here:

```
exports.keylist = function(){
return exports.connectDB()
.then(SQNote => {
    return SQNote.findAll({ attributes: [ 'notekey' ] })
    .then(notes => {
        return notes.map(note => notekey);
    });
});};
```

Error:
[error in browser picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYYHZ.png)

SQNote.findAll is not a function

TypeError: SQNote.findAll is not a function
    at exports.connectDB.then.SQNote (/home/vegas/NodeJS_course/notes/models/notes-sequelize.js:119:23)
    at anonymous

Answer (score 1):

After spend another few hours I found my mistake. 
Should be:

```
return SQNote.sync();
```

Instead:

```
return SQNote.sync;
```